# Bound events are lost when using jQuery.append

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, dom-manipulation

I have a simple code like this http://jsfiddle.net/9braK/2/

```
$(function(){

$('body').append(
    $("<a/>").attr({ "id": "foo", "href":"#" })
             .text("click me")
             .live("click",function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                alert("Hello World!");
             })
  );
});
```

According to the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/append/) this should work, right?

Comment: syntax error on line e.preventDefault(). put a comma :)

Comment: Sorry.. typing mistake but that's not the problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> DOM traversal methods are not
>   supported for finding elements to send
>   to .live(). Rather, the .live() method
>   should always be called directly after
>   a selector, as in the example above.

[Source](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

So the only problem in your code is the usage of `live()`. `"<a/>"` is not a selector, and the way `live()` works it won't be able to find corresponding elements. If you simply use `.click()`, it will work flawlessly of course.

You can use something like

```
$('body')
  .append(
    $("<a/>")
      .attr({ "id": "foo", "href":"#" })
      .text("click me")
    )
  )
  .delegate("#foo", "click", function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                alert("Hello World!");
             });
```

to achieve what you wanted (but I think a simple `click()` would be sufficient depending on your use case).

Answer (score 0):

This one works :

```
$(function(){
  // Add the click event for all future elements having the id #foo
  $('#foo').live("click",function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    alert("Hello World!");
                 });

    $('body').append(
        $("<a/>").attr({ "id": "foo", "href":"#" })
                 .text("Continue ")
    );
});
```